# Determine which key is successfully used for authentication with AuthorizedKeyCommands

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

As of [OpenSSH 6.2](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.2), the option to use an external program for key pair based authentication is available with `AuthorizedKeysCommand`.

According to the `sshd_config` [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config), this program should return zero or more lines of `authorized_keys` output.

**Assuming the configured program returns multiple keys, is there a way (downstream in, say, the `ForceCommand`) to determine which of the returned keys was used to authenticate?**

For example, this works great if you have a separate user for each key.  However, if you're sharing a user (i.e. 'git') and you want to use a daemon wide `ForceCommand` (configured in the sshd_config), you lose the context of which externally identified user and which key was used to authenticate.

Gitlab (and Gitosis) does something similar where it shares a 'git' user but maintains the `authorized_keys` file to [associate a `key_id` command line argument with their `command=` option](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell/blob/master/lib/gitlab_keys.rb#L75) that allows them to then externally determine permissions.  This appears to be how they link the key authentication with the force command.

This solution works great on a smaller scale, but seems like a nightmare to scale to many millions of users that, say, Github has.

Do large scale, highly available SSH installations run their own forked version of OpenSSH?  I don't see a way to chain `AuthorizedKeysCommand` and `ForceCommand` without maintaining (like an animal) files in a vanilla OpenSSH setup.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you are generating a list of authorized keys dynamically, I don't see how it could be a problem to put the command on each line of the output along with an argument uniquely identifying the key on that line. Then you wouldn't even need to use `ForceCommand`.

Comment: @kasperd interesting. I hadn't even thought of generating the command.  I imagine since the only requirement is it match the authorized_key format, that would work. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AuthorizedKeysCommand` description in the [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5)

> should produce on standard output zero or more lines of authorized_keys output

This means you can generate a `command=` option complete w/ command line arguments (or any other valid `authorized_key` option).

For example, the dynamically generated line could be something like:

`no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="/path/to/program arg1 arg2 arg3'" ssh-rsa bigHugeLongLongKey alias`

Thanks @kasperd for the direction!